# Extracting data form another section with same ID (Appcelerator)

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, appcelerator

I have the following JSON: (its simplified a bit for you)

```
{ returnJSON = {
    studentDataVOs = {
        finalGrades = (
            {
                grade = A;
                percent = 100;
                sectionid = 7744;
                reportingTermId = 801;
            },
            {
                grade = B+;
                percent = 89;
                sectionid = 7745;
                reportingTermID = 801;
            });
        reportingTerms = (
            {
                id = 801;
                title = S1;
            },
            {
                id = 802;
                title = S2;
            });
        sections = (
            {
                id = 7744;
                termID = 801;
                courseTitle = Physics;
                courseCode = 88A;
            },
            {
                id = 7745;
                termID = 801;
                courseTitle = Government;
                courseCode = 90B;
            });
        };
    };
}
```

I am building an app using Appcelerator Titanium that displays a table view with the data hopefully showing the following:

---

Physics (88A) - S1 (Grade: A, 100%)

---

Government (90B) - S1 (Grade: B+, 89%)

---

...and so on...

I have the table view set up and the following code extracts the data from the sections and puts it in the labels of the table view:

```
var response = JSON.parse(response);
var sections = response.returnJSON.studentDataVOs.sections;
for (i=0;i<sections.length;i++) {
    var courseName = sections[i].courseTitle;
    var courseCode = sections[i].courseCode;
}
```

What I cannot figure out is how to go about fetching the grade, and term title for each individual class. As you can see, the data for each section contains an ID and termID, which direct me to a section in the finalGrades and reportingTerms that contains the ID or termID, where I need to fetch the final grades, percents, and term titles.

Can anyone help me with this? I have been trying on and off for two days trying to figure this out...

Answer (score 0):

You should create indexes for each field you've listed. It's pretty simple:

```js
//for example you have user list
var users = [{
    id : 1, email : 'user@gmail.com',
    nickname : 'John'
}, {
    id : 2, email : 'user@stackoverflow.com',
    nickname : 'Peter'
}];

//and you need to query user by his email, id and nickname
//first, create 3 index list

var usersIdIndex = {}, usersEmailIndex = {},
    usersNicknameIndex = {};

//then fill them

users.forEach(function(user){
    usersIdIndex[user.id] = user;
    usersEmailIndex[user.email] = user;
    usersNicknameIndex[user.nickname] = user;
});

//now you can get users by any of this fields
//for example

console.log(usersIdIndex[2].nickname== 'Peter');
console.log(usersNicknameIndex['John'].email == 'user@gmail.com');
```

Comment: I'd like to see an example using the original question's data.  I'm having trouble connecting the dot between the examples.  This seems like a potentially interesting solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sections -> Final Grades

In the sections list, I would pass a variable in the tablerow that I could use to query for the next set of data.  You need the section id to associate the data with the data in the final grade, so I would add it to my table row.
When creating your table:

```
// This loop to loop through the data.
function getSections(_args){
   var response = JSON.parse(response);
   var sections = response.returnJSON.studentDataVOs.sections;
    for (i=0;i<sections.length;i++) {
       createMyRow({
         courseName: sections[i].courseTitle,
         courseCode: sections[i].courseCode,
         sectionId: sections[i].id
       });
    }
}

// This function creates the rows for the table 
function createMyRow(_args){
   // the sectionId is now included in the tableRow and can be used later for your 
   // next query.
   // allows the sectionId value is now can be queried when a user clicks it 
   // through e.rowData.
   var tableRow = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
      sectionId: _args.sectionId
   });

   var title = Ti.UI.createLabel({
      text: _args.courseName
   });
   tableRow.add(title);

    return tableRow;
    }

    var tableView = Ti.UI.createTableView();
var data = [];
function refreshTable()

   data = getSections();
   var rows = [];
   for( var i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
      rows.push(createMyRow(data[i]);
   }
   tableView.setData(rows);
}

// this passes the value of the sectionId so you can use it to look up your next section.
tableView.addEventListener('click', function(e){
   getFinalGrades({
      sectionId: e.rowData.sectionId
   })
});
function getFinalGrades(_args){
   var finalGrades = response.returnJSON.studentDataVOs.finalGrades
   var data = [];
   for (i=0;i<finalGrades.length;i++) {
     if(finalGrades[i].sectionId == _args.sectionId){
       data.push({
         grade: finalGrades[i].grade,
         percent: finalGrades[i].percent
       });
     }
   }
   return data;
}
```

I hacked this together rather quickly looking at some of my code examples.  At the end of the getFinalGrades function, you would have an array of finalGrades that were only from sectionId you clicked.